# How to identify most important Amino Acid residues in a given protein?

Tags: sequence-alignment, protein-structure

Continuing from the title, in my context, important means that changing the set of AAs (either or one more many) changes the domain and/or fold and/or function and/or family etc.

I  noticed that there are two types of methods Protbert (protein language models, sequence-based methods) and/or Alphafold (structure (tertiary) based methods); one needs both methods to "reallY" identify the essential set of AAs in a given protein?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry. This question is ill posed as it completely depends on context —namely is simply a question of **what are the main roles AA residues can take**. Core residues when mutated may cause and increase in Gibbs free energy of folding (i.e. less energy is released when folded from a magically linear protein form), these are key to Structure as seen in **PDB** and predicted by Alphafold. Catalytic residues are key to activity. Channel gate residues are key to permeability. etc etc etc etc

Comment: Do you have many examples of your protein from different species? Can you look at alignments of the various homologs?